# PHP preg_match bible scripture format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am struggling with building a regular expression for parsing this kind of strings (bible scriptures):

```
  'John 14:16–17, 25–26'
  'John 14:16–17'
  'John 14:16'
  'John 14'
  'John'
```

So the basic pattern is:

`Book [[Chapter][:Verse]]`

where chapter and verse is optional.

Comment: So it should match even if it's just the book's name? Do you have a list of books that it should match? Otherwise it would just match every word.

Comment: Just match any word, the real problem for me is having so many optional parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this here

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+\d+)?(?::\d+(?:–\d+)?(?:,\s*\d+(?:–\d+)?)*)?
```

See and test it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30h4b)

Because of the `(?:,\s*\d+(?:–\d+)?)*` at the end you can have a list of verses, verses ranges at the end.

Comment: Yours is the most general one. I only added `[-–]` instead of hyphen as @Robby suggested and some capturing brackets to make it perfect.

Answer (score 9):

I think this does what you need:

```
\w+\s?(\d{1,2})?(:\d{1,2})?([-–]\d{1,2})?(,\s\d{1,2}[-–]\d{1,2})?
```

Assumptions:

- The numbers are always in sets of either 1 or 2 digits
- The dash will match either of the following `-` and `–`

Below is the regex with comments:

```
"
\w         # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   +          # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s         # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   ?          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,2}      # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)?         # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   :          # Match the character “:” literally
   \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,2}      # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)?         # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [-–]       # Match a single character present in the list “-–”
   \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,2}      # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)?         # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4
   ,          # Match the character “,” literally
   \s         # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,2}      # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [-–]       # Match a single character present in the list “-–”
   \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,2}      # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)?         # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

And here are some examples of its usage in php:

```
if (preg_match('/\w+\s?(\d{1,2})?(:\d{1,2})?([-–]\d{1,2})?(,\s\d{1,2}[-–]\d{1,2})?/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Get an array of all matches in a given string

```
preg_match_all('/\w+\s?(\d{1,2})?(:\d{1,2})?([-–]\d{1,2})?(,\s\d{1,2}[-–]\d{1,2})?/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: So it will match either dash or hyphen?

Comment: You cannot assume a chapter number is under 100; the book Psalms has 150 chapters.

Answer (score 3):

**Use this regex :**

```
[A-Za-z]+( ([0-9]+)(:[0-9]+)?([\-–][0-9]+)?(, [0-9]+[\-–][0-9]+)?)?
```

**Or in its 'prettier' version :**

```
\w+( (\d+)(:\d+)?([\-–]\d+)?(, \d+[\-–]\d+)?)?
```

---

**UPDATED :** To match dashes or hyphens

---

***NOTE :*** I've tested it and it matches ALL 5 possible versions.

Example : http://regexr.com?30h4q

[image]

Comment: This is good, but it fails on references like "1 Corinthians 2:11"

Answer (score 1):

```
   (\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\s\d+)(:\d+)+([-–]\d+)?([,;](\s)?(\d+:)?\d+([-–]\d+)?)?
```

This is a hybrid of all code presented here. The only formats it will not highlight are "*book name only*" or "*book & chapter only*" (just add "*:1-all*" after chapter #) I found the other codes provided to qualify too many variations, not in line with bible verse syntax.

**These are the examples I tested in RegExr:** (can't post images yet)

> <strike>John</strike> **humbolt 14:16–17, 25–26** 
>   **John 14:16–17** 
>   **John 14:16** 
>   **John 77:3; 2:9-11** 
>   **John 5:1-all** <strike>brad 555-783-6867</strike> 
>   <strike>John 6</strike> 
>   <strike>hi there how are you</strike> 
>   **Ezra 32:5** **John 14:16-17, 25-36** 
>   <strike>12</strike> <strike>23:34</strike> 
>   **John 14:16-17,25-36** 
>   **John 14:16-17; 32:25**

Comment: Every other regex in this page was grabbing extra text when I deployed them. This one seems to only grab the verse, which is what I want. EXAMPLE: https://regex101.com/r/od1s1T/1

Answer (score 0):

```
([1|2|3]?([i|I]+)?(\s?)\w+(\s+?))((\d+)?(,?)(\s?)(\d+))+(:?)((\d+)?([\-–]\d+)?(,(\s?)\d+[\-–]\d+)?)?
```

works for almost every book...