# Regex scripture match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have the following regex code that i'm trying to perfect for scripture searches. ... are rest of 66 Bible Books.

```
/(?=\S)\b(genesis|exodus|leviticus|...)(\.)?(\s)?((\d{1,3})([:,-;]?(?=\d))?((\d{1,3})?([:,-;]?(?=\d))?){0,50})/iu
```

Where I'm running into the issue is that is with multiple passage references like 
Genesis 3:2 1 Chronicles 2:2 if I use a regex with also a space in search the function assumes that 1 in Chronicles is Genesis 1 and does not recognize it and send it to `preg_replace_callback`. Any suggestions?

The input is a `string` that is whole paragraph like

```
Mat 3:12; Luke 3:17; Revelation 16:14 • gathered, 7 Mat 2:4; Mat 22:34; Mat 27:27; Mar 4:1; Mar 5:21; Joh 11:47; Act 4:26 • into, 1 Revelation 13:10 • resorted, 1 Joh 18:2 • themselves, 1 Act 11:26 • together, 24 Mat 13:2; Mat 22:41; Mat 26:3; Mat 27:17; Mat 27:62; Mar 2:2; Mar 6:30; Mar 7:1; Luke 22:66; Joh 11:52; Act 4:6; Act 4:27; Act 4:31; Act 13:44; Act 14:27; Act 15:6; Act 15:30; Act 20:7; Act 20:8; 1 Corinthians 5:4; Revelation 16:16; Revelation 19:17; Revelation 19:19; Revelation 20:8
```

what I'm trying to do is make it so that it would match the scripture and passage and then turn it into an a `href` link using `pre_replace_callback` function.

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and what you want for the output?

Comment: ^ with at least one or two passages before and after the problematic passage.

Comment: Here is another post about it to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974012/php-preg-match-bible-scripture-format

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add your clarifications, rather than using comments (which you could then delete)?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974012/php-preg-match-bible-scripture-format#9974191) provided by @danielson317 in the comments and extend it to suit your needs. It will even handle "Genesis 3:2 1 Chronicles 2:2" correctly, giving you `<a href...>Genesis 3:2</a> <a href...>1 Chronicles 2:2</a>`.

You can even make it a class:

```
<?php
$scriptureUtils = new ScriptureUtils();
echo $scriptureUtils->addLinks($text);

class ScriptureUtils {

    private $booksAbbreviated = array(
        "Gen", "Exo", "Lev", "Num", "Deu", "Jos", "Jud", "Rut", "1 Sam", "2 Sam", "1 Kin", 
        "2 Kin", "1 Chr", "2 Chr", "Ezr", "Neh", "Est", "Job", "Psa", "Pro", "Ecc", "Son", 
        "Isa", "Jer", "Lam", "Eze", "Dan", "Hos", "Joe", "Amo", "Oba", "Jon", "Mic", 
        "Nah", "Hab", "Zep", "Hag", "Zec", "Mal", "Mat", "Mar", "Luk", "Joh", "Act", 
        "Rom", "1 Cor", "2 Cor", "Gal", "Eph", "Phi", "Col", "1 The", "2 The", "1 Tim", 
        "2 Tim", "Tit", "Phi", "Heb", "Jam", "1 Pet", "2 Pet", "1 Joh", "2 Joh", "3 Joh", 
        "Jud", "Rev"
    );

    private $booksFullnames = array(
        "Genesis", "Exodus", "Leviticus", "Numbers", "Deuteronomy", "Joshua", "Judges", 
        "Ruth", "1 Samuel", "2 Samuel", "1 Kings", "2 Kings", "1 Chronicles", 
        "2 Chronicles", "Ezra", "Nehemiah", "Esther", "Job", "Psalms", "Proverbs", 
        "Ecclesiastes", "Song of Solomon", "Isaiah", "Jeremiah", "Lamentations", "Ezekiel", 
        "Daniel", "Hosea", "Joel", "Amos", "Obadiah", "Jonah", "Micah", "Nahum", 
        "Habakkuk", "Zephaniah", "Haggai", "Zechariah", "Malachi", "Matthew", "Mark", 
        "Luke", "John", "Acts", "Romans", "1 Corinthians", "2 Corinthians", "Galatians", 
        "Ephesians", "Philippians", "Colossians", "1 Thessalonians", "2 Thessalonians", 
        "1 Timothy", "2 Timothy", "Titus", "Philemon", "Hebrews", "James", "1 Peter", 
        "2 Peter", "1 John", "2 John", "3 John", "Jude", "Revelation"
    );

    private $addLinkPattern;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->defineLinkPattern();
    }

    public function addLinks($text) {
        $returnString = preg_replace_callback(
            $this->addLinkPattern,
            array($this, "addLinkCallback"),
            $text
        );
        return $returnString;
    }

    private function addLinkCallback($matches) {
        $returnString = "";
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $returnString .= "<a href=\"bible.php?passage=$match\">$match</a>";
        }
        return $returnString;
    }

    private function defineLinkPattern() {
        // It is important that the full names appear before the abbreviated ones.
        $bookList = implode("|", array_merge($this->booksFullnames, $this->booksAbbreviated));
        $this->addLinkPattern = "/\\b(?:$bookList)(?:\\s+\\d+)?(?::\\d+(?:–\\d+)?(?:,\\s*\\d+(?:–\\d+)?)*)?/";
    }

}
```